# How to tell whether an extension method affects 'this' or not?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, immutability

I know that String extension methods return a String and do not actually affect the variable calling the extension method (so it's immutable) - but how do I tell whether other extension methods do or not? For example, I'm working with a `List<NewsItem>` - and I need to order this list by date descending, so I've written this code:

```
newsItems.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date);
```

Does this affect the newsItems list or *just* return the IOrderedEnumerable??

In other words, should the above code actually read:

```
newsItems = newsItems.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).ToList();
```

??

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: You can actually test his yourself you know... Just put 3 numbers in a list and see if they get sorted or not.

Comment: My question is how can you tell? It seems unnecessary to run such a test every time I wanted to know if an extension method had this effect or not.

Comment: String extension methods cannot change the string, as strings are immutable.

Comment: I know that, I did mention that in my original post. Why has someone voted to close the question??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, which itself provides *read-only* access. Of course, the extension method could *cast* to `List<T>`, but basically none of the LINQ to Objects extension methods affect their target (assuming the targets aren't affected by iteration, of course).

LINQ is designed in a functional style - methods return a new view on the data rather than changing the target they're called on.

EDIT: As noted by drew, the `[Pure]` attribute can be used as an indication of this, and some tools will pick up on it. However:

- You still need to trust that the `[Pure]` attribute has been correctly applied
- It's not always easy to tell whether or not there *is* a `[Pure]` attribute (it doesn't show up in the docs I linked to, for example)
- You should probably be reading the documentation for anything you call anyway, if you aren't confident in what it does

Comment: Thanks Jon. I happen to now know this about Strings, and now about the LINQ extensions - is it just a case of experience (knowing what extensions do and don't affect their target) or is there a way of looking at the extension method to be able to tell??

Comment: @DanielMcNulty: You read the documentation, basically - there's nothing different about extension methods here to any other methods. If you're going to call something, you should understand what it's going to do, which usually involves reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, that's all I was after - some clarification as to whether it is just a case of knowing from experience and documentation what I'm using - and it makes sense to be fair. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonSkeet, what Daniel is asking is possible via the right tooling and the `PureAttribute` (explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940353/24874)).

Comment: @DrewNoakes: That will tell in some cases, yes - but it's not always obvious, and won't always be applied even when it could be. Will edit.

Answer (score 2):

All of the Linq extension methods only perform query operations over sequences, so assume that they're read only (queries).  So, they return `IEnumerable<T>` instances that provide sequences of values representing the result of the operation.

Of course there's nothing stopping you making an extension method that modifies the object to which it's applied (`this`).

The API contains metadata that is useful in this case however.  The [`PureAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx) attribute can be used on method that have no side effects.  If you use a tool such as ReSharper in your IDE, then it will warn you when you try to call a pure method and do not use the result.  Because such a method is pure, it has no visible side effects elsewhere in memory, and so ignoring the result is a bit daft.  The Linq operators are annotated with this attribute.  So it `object.ToString()` for example.  You can also use this attribute on your own code.

tl;dr R# would have found your bug in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Generally by the parameter (value type or reference type) and secondly by the return type.

If you have a method signature such `DateTime DateTime.AddDays(int days)` you are getting two hints that the method does not affect the original datetime - firstly that DateTime is a value type, secondly that it returns a DateTime. Value types, if modified in the method body will only have their changes applied locally to the copy on the stack. Unless the value type is returned the caller can never observe those changes. Reference types by contrast can be modified in a calling method and have the modifications observed by the caller.

Similarly if you have a method such as `IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)`, despite the fact that the input type is a reference type (and can be modified), the hint is that as a new type is returned the original will remain unmodified.

Finally, this can be confirmed through testing. As a general point of interest the LINQ method chain extension methods all return a new `IEnumerable<T>`, are lazy evaluated and don't modify the contents `IEnumerable<T>` passed in, instead applying a filter which is evaluated when `GetEnumerator` is called on the the returned `IEnumerable<T>.`